# Field Set for custom setting

Tags: customsetting, fieldsets

Can we define a field set for a custom setting ? If yes, where do I do that ?

If it's not possible, getting all the fields from custom setting will also do, which I can get using `getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet()`. but the problem with this is that I also get the standard fields from the custom setting like createddate,createdbyid etc which I don't want. is there a way to only get all the custom fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom settings don't have field sets. You can determine which fields are custom because the API name ends with __c. Also describing the fields will return true for the IsCustom method.